# Query not working when trigger is enabled

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, triggers

I've got some triggers in my table so I can log any change made by the users in my website. Then I found out that in some tables the queries were falling silently because no error was triggered in my php code. I tried disabling my triggers and then they worked. I also noticed that when I put a `die` after the queries they worked with the triggers enabled. Also when I run the queries in SQL Manager they also work without any errors. Do you have any idea why this is happening? How can I see if the triggers are failing?

My example of a trigger (there's only one insert at a time):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WorkflowBase_insert]
ON [dbo].[WorkflowBase]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @id INT,
        @result varchar(MAX),
        @user varchar(MAX),
        @LoopCounter INT = 1, 
        @MAX INT, 
        @Column NVARCHAR(100),
        @Type NVARCHAR(100),
        @Value NVARCHAR(100),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Tmp NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @result = '{'

    SELECT @user = system_user

    SELECT @MAX = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'WorkflowBase'

    WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MAX)
    BEGIN
       SELECT @Column = COLUMN_NAME, @Type = DATA_TYPE
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @LoopCounter and TABLE_NAME = 'WorkflowBase'

       Select * into #inserted from inserted

       SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #inserted'

       exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @Value out

       DROP TABLE #inserted

       IF (@Value is not null or @Value != '') and  (@Type = 'int' or @Type = 'varchar' or @Type = 'nvarchar')
       BEGIN
            IF @result = '{'
            BEGIN
                SET @result = @result + ' "' + @Column + '":"' + @Value + '"'
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @result = @result + ', "' + @Column + '":"' + @Value + '"'
            END
       END
       ELSE IF (@Value is not null or @Value != '') and  (@Type = 'datetime2' or @Type = 'datetime' or @Type = 'date')
       BEGIN
            IF @result = '{'
            BEGIN
                SET @result = @result + ' "' + @Column + '":"' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Value,120) + '"'
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @result = @result + ', "' + @Column + '":"' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Value,120) + '"'
            END
       END
       SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1        
    END

    SET @result = @result + '}'

    SELECT @id = inserted.ID FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO sys_logs (username,datahora,tabela,[object_id],[action],newvalue) values (@user,GETDATE(),'WorkflowBase',@id,'INSERT',@result)

END
```

And the code where the queries fail:

```
foreach ($z as $k => $v)
        {
            $_xuser = array();
            $_user = array();
            $ordem = str_pad($k, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);


            $performers = $v["Utilizador"];


            $_form = explode("|", $v["Definicoes"]["Operation"]);

            $Duration = $v["Definicoes"]["Duration"];
            $Advanced_Function = $v["Definicoes"]["Advanced_Function"];
            $Note = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($v["Definicoes"]["Note"]));
            $PaiGUID = "'" . $v["PaiGUID"] ."'";
            $RouteToGUID = "'" . $v["RouteToGUID"] . "'";

            if ($v["PaiGUID"] == "")
                $PaiGUID = "null";

            if ($v["RouteToGUID"] == "")
                $RouteToGUID = "null";

            $sql = "INSERT INTO WorkflowBase (
            [IDGuid]
      ,[IDWorkflowDefinition]
      ,[TaskType]
      ,[TaskName]
      ,[Ordem]
      ,[DescriptionText]
      ,[Duration]
      ,[IDOwners]
      ,[IDOperation]
      ,[IDParent]
      ,[NextTask]
      ,[ExternalFunction]
      ,[Condition]
      ,[ExplanatoryNote]
      ,[IDSubProcess]
            ) VALUES (
            '$v[GUID]'
            ,'$wf'
            ,'$v[Tipo]'
            ,'$v[Nome]'
            ,'$ordem'
            ,'$v[Descricao]'
            ,'$Duration'
            ,'$performers'
            ,'" . trim($_form[0]) . "'
            ,$PaiGUID
            ,$RouteToGUID
            ,'$Advanced_Function'
            ,'$v[Condicao]'
            ,'$Note'
      ,'$SubProcess'
            ) 
            ";


            ($res = cms_sqlsrv_query($sql)) || exit(cms_error());



        }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Please share necessary code as per [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines otherwise we can't assist you well.

Comment: @JonathonOgden already updated my question.

Comment: What is this trigger trying to do? Using loops like this in a trigger is almost always a sign of a very bad design decision somewhere along the way.

Comment: Also, your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation and as such they need to be set based. You can and will get more than 1 row inserted at some point and your logic is going to fail.

Comment: @SeanLange my trigger is going trough the column names of the defined table and for each column gets the value and saves it in my log table.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. So your log table is an EAV style of log? I have used those in the past and they are very challenging to work with. The problem comes when management says, "You log this table so can you give me the details of what the table looked like on such and such day". It is incredibly painful to put that together. You will need to also loop through every row in inserted if you stick with this type of logging. Since you are not capturing the "whodunnit" data have you considered using CDC instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @SeanLange I need to loop through the inserted table even if I know there's only one insert at the time? Can you explain me better what is CDC or give me a link? (when I searched I only found control disease stuff)

Comment: @patricia you can't possibly be 100% certain there will only ever be a single row inserted. That may be how it works today but that is a dangerous assumption. CDC = Change Data Capture. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645938.aspx and https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-(cdc)-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @SeanLange but do you have any idea why this is happening in my triggers?

Comment: @SeanLange in the CDC I can see which user change the data? I want to display the changes in my site so the admin can see who changed data and what they changed.

Comment: One major limitation of CDC is the inability to see "whodunnit". I can't tell you why your trigger is sometimes failing with no error message. But honestly, I wouldn't spend any time on figuring it out because they need to be rewritten. You might also reconsider the EAV style logging going on. Look at back at my previous comment about how painful that really is when you need to review audit information.

Comment: @SeanLange I changed my trigger to loop trough the rows in the inserted table. I output the query and run it in `SQL Server Management` and everything goes fine. But if let my php script run it then the data isn't saved nor the trigger.

Comment: Using a loop in a trigger is a recipe for horrible performance. The way your trigger is coded you now have nested loops. This is going to bite you one day and you will have to eventually write this into a set based approach because the performance is just going to be bad.

Comment: @SeanLange do you suggest to write the trigger in another way? how? :)

Comment: @SeanLange I mean, can I write it without the loops?

Comment: You could if you move away from the EAV style auditing table. As long as that type of auditing is in place you are kind of stuck.